# Laravel-8 erro com função Cache::remember()

Tags: php, laravel, cache, redis, laravel-8

Minha aplicação está retornando um erro ao armazenar o cache, vi que estava salvando, mas está retornando este erro. Alguém pode dizer o porquê? Aqui está minha função e o erro:

função que retorna erro:

```
       <?php

namespace App\Repositories\ProductFilter;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Repositories\Contracts\IProductFilterRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class ProductFilterRepository implements IProductFilterRepository
{
   
    public function getProductsRecommendations($keywords)
    {
        $expiration = 10;
        $keyName = 'productsRecommended';

        return Cache::remember($keyName, $expiration, function ($keywords) {
            return  Product::query()->where(function ($productsAll) use ($keywords) {
                if ($keywords) {
                    foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
                        $productsAll->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orWhere('code', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
                }
            })->where('status', 'active')->get();
        });
    }
}
```

error:

```
ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Repositories\ProductFilter\ProductFilterRepository::App\Repositories\ProductFilter\{closure}(), 0 passed in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php on line 385 and exactly 1 expected
http://localhost:8888/recommended
```

Meu .env com as configurações do cache:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_URL=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT = redis
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: erro por falta de argumentos, não tem como saber só com o que colocou, é um erro local de desenvolvimento

Comment: @novic coloquei mais informações na minha pergunta. Olha se vc sabe, por favor.

Comment: Parece ser o `namespace` dá uma olhada aonde você utiliza isso porque parece ai ser o problema!

Comment: @novic se te interessar eu postei uma resposta com o que estava dando errado na minha função. Agradeço pela disposição em tentar me ajudar. Muito obrigado. Beyoncé te abençoe.

Answer (score 0):

O problema era que eu estava usando `function($ keywords)`, mas deveria estar usando `function() use ($ keywords)` porque, no código-fonte, você vê que está pedindo `$value = $callback()`, mas a função está esperando `$keywords`, se você quiser compartilhar um valor, deverá usar use ($ keywords) novamente, como sua segunda função em where.

```
return Cache::remember($keyName, $expiration, function () use ($keywords)
```

Esta solução obtive no [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952439/laravel-8-error-with-cacheremember-function-doesnt-work)
Espero que ajude outras pessoas.

Comment: Só pra completar você pode usar o helper cache https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-cache . Ficaria cache()->remember.. cache()->get etc.